# how to access any job properties using NameValueCollection in Quartz.Net?

Tags: c#, .net, scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

i have a big project about Quartz.net. i have been created some job to make some tasks. So i have been made a summary project to understand me. i have a job. i want to parse some values to job's properties. while execute time, job needs to these properties. But i can not do that. Please dont say "why dont use 'JobDetail.JobDataMap' ?" i need below structure:

[image]

Look JobBase:

```
 public abstract class JobBase : MarshalByRefObject, IStatefulJob
{
    void IJob.Execute(JobExecutionContext context)
    {
        this.Execute();
    }

    protected abstract void Execute();
}
```

also Test.cs (it is MY JOB!)

Test.cs:

```
 public class Test : JobBase
{

    public string FileName { get; set; }

    public string Ip { get; set; }


    protected override void Execute()
    {
        Ping ping = new Ping();
        PingReply pingReply = ping.Send(Ip);
        using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(FileName, true))
        {
            file.WriteLine(pingReply.Address);
        }  
    }
}
```

My Project to start schedule :

```
   private void btnProperties_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ISchedulerFactory schedfabrikayeni;
        IScheduler schedyeni;
        JobDetail job;
        CronTrigger trigeryeni;
        NameValueCollection properties = new NameValueCollection();
        properties["FileName"] = @"C:\temp\pingresult.txt";
        properties["Ip"] = "192.168.16.14";


        schedfabrikayeni = new StdSchedulerFactory(properties);
        schedyeni = schedfabrikayeni.GetScheduler();
        job = new JobDetail("myJob", null, typeof(Test));

        JobDataMap map = new JobDataMap();
        map.Put("msg", "Your remotely added job has executed!");
        job.JobDataMap = map;
        string cronExpressiontxt = string.Empty;
        //0 0 12 1 4 ? *
        cronExpressiontxt = "0 0/1 * 1/1 * ? *";
        trigeryeni = new CronTrigger("triger1", null, "myJob", null, cronExpressiontxt);

        schedyeni.ScheduleJob(job, trigeryeni);
        schedyeni.Start();
    }
```

But my Ip is null My FileName is null. how to set properties using below usage:

```
  NameValueCollection properties = new NameValueCollection();
        properties["FileName"] = @"C:\temp\pingresult.txt";
        properties["Ip"] = "192.168.16.14";


        schedfabrikayeni = new StdSchedulerFactory(properties);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to agreed with @jvilalta and @sgmoore, you need to use the JobDataMap to store the stateful data. Here is an example how I used the JobDataMap property:

```
    protected override void ExecuteWorker(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            SomeProcessor someProcessor;

            // If the JobDataMap doesn't contain the initialized key yet, then this job hasn't been run before.
            // Initialize state data if this is the case; otherwise, get state data from the JobDataMap.
            if (!context.JobDetail.JobDataMap.Contains(QUARTZ_KEY_PROCESSOR))
            {
                someProcessor = someProcessorFactory.Create();

                if (someProcessor == null)
                    return;

                context.JobDetail.JobDataMap[QUARTZ_KEY_PROCESSOR] = someProcessor;
            }
            else
            {
                someProcessor = (someProcessor)context.JobDetail.JobDataMap[QUARTZ_KEY_PROCESSOR];
            }

            ExecuteETL(someProcessor, DateTime.MaxValue);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            m_log.Fatal("Scheduled job execution failed.", e);
            // This method can only throw a JobExecutionException.
            // http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/tutorial/lesson_3.html
            throw new JobExecutionException(e);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Where did you get the idea that this would work? I've not see any examples like this.

I could be wrong, but as I understood it, the NameValueCollection properties that you pass to the scheduler are settings to configure how the scheduler itself works. For example, if you want your scheduler to use a sql database you can set (amongst other things) the value of quartz.jobStore.type to  "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX, Quartz".

I assumed if you passed any extra properties that the scheduler didn't know about, they would simple get ignored.

In particular, there does not seem to be any way to access the properties on the scheduler, which would again suggest there are only needed/used to initialise the scheduler.

> Please dont say "why dont use 'JobDetail.JobDataMap' ?"

JobDataMap would appear to be designed for exactly this purpose. If there is some reason why it does not work for you, you would be better to explain **why** it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by implementing a custom scheduler factory and/or a custom job factory. The default scheduler and job factories do not support setting job properties like you describe. The JobDataMap is the correct way to pass parameters to the job, as @sgmoore notes.

FWIW, the code as you have it will not work. The scheduler itself needs to be managed as a singleton and the reference to it, once created, needs to be maintained for as long as the scheduler needs to be up and running. Otherwise it will be garbage collected.

Here are some [posts I wrote](http://jayvilalta.com/blog/tag/ijobfactory/) that might be of interest if you decide to implement a job factory.